# Problem with view (read-only mode for vim)

Tags: vim

Sometimes when I'm editing code in a terminal, I want to open the same file in read-only mode using /usr/bin/view. However, when I do this, vim still warns me that a swap file exists. Why is this? I thought that view was explicitly read-only. Any ideas? Do I have something bogus in my system? I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Usually swap files are created when you have already opened the same file in another terminal, or if you put your vi/vim in background with `ctrl+z`
Removing the .YOURFILE.swp will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Like you already said `view` is the read-only mode for `vim` - so effectively you are opening the same file two times with `vim`.

As `vim` doesn't check if there is another instance running with the same file open it will warn you about the swap file.

If you don't need swap files you can disable them permanently with `set noswapfile` in your `.vimrc`.

To only ignore swap files when using `view` you can use `view -n` to ignore the swap file. To avoid to type this every time, add `alias view="view -n"` to your shells rc file (most probably `.bashrc`).